# Generating random number within the range of 2 specific arrays (Within 2D array)

Tags: java

I'm trying to figure out how to read a csv file, full of integers in 2D array then have the specific rows and columns populated then generate random numbers between those 2 numbers.

E.g.

**1,2**,3,4,5

**2,5**,6,4,3

**2,4**,6,7,8

How do I generate the 3 rows of random numbers of the bold numbers?

```
Random r = new Random();
int low = [];
int high = [];
int num= r.nextInt(high-low) + low;
return num;
 
//tried using for loop with i & j as well but with no success.
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What do you mean with the comment "//tried using for loop with i & j as well but with no success."?

Comment: just as an example..
for(int i = 0; i<rows; i++)
       {
           for(int j=0; j<columns; j++)
           {
               System.out.print(selection[i][j] + "\t");
           }

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I did split them but how would you take the two indexes and generate random numbers? you mean like each row manually?

Answer (score 0):

- Read your csv line-by-line or all lines at once and store in a list,
- create a 2D-array with the same length as the size of the list
- split each line from the list at comma, parse each element to int and store in a 2d-array,
- take first and second index of each row of your array and check which
  one is the smallest and the biggest using `Math.min`nand `Math.max`
- generate your random numbers using min and max

example code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

public final class Example {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        List<String> linesFromCsv = Files.readAllLines(Path.of("path to your csv"));

        int[][] matrix = new int[linesFromCsv.size()][];

        for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
            String[] split = linesFromCsv.get(i).split(",");
            matrix[i] = new int[split.length];
            for (int j = 0; j < split.length; j++){
                matrix[i][j] = Integer.parseInt(split[j]);
            }
        }

        Random random = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++){
            int low  = Math.min(matrix[i][0], matrix[i][1]);
            int high = Math.max(matrix[i][0], matrix[i][1]);

            int randNum = random.nextInt(high-low) + low;

            System.out.println("random number for line: " + (i + 1)
                               + " between low: " + low + " and high: " + high + " --> " + randNum);
        }
    }
}
```